# PyMC3 sample() function does not accept the "start" value to generate a trace

Tags: bayesian, pymc3

I am new to PyMC3 and Bayesian inference methods. I have a simple code that tries to infer the value of some decay constant (=1) from the artificial data generated using a truncated exponential distribution:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pymc3 as pm
import arviz as az


T = stats.truncexpon(b = 10.)
t = T.rvs(1000)

#Bayesian Inference

with pm.Model() as model: 
    #Define Priors
    lam = pm.Gamma('$\lambda$', alpha=1, beta=1)

    #Define Likelihood
    time = pm.Exponential('time', lam = lam, observed = t)

    #Inference
    trace = pm.sample(20, start = {'lam': 10.}, \
            step=pm.Metropolis(), chains=1, cores=1, \
            progressbar = True)


az.plot_trace(trace)
plt.show()
```

This code produces a trace like below

[image]

I am really confused as to why the starting value of 10. is not accepted by the sampler. The trace above should start at 10. I am using python 3.7 to run the code.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you elaborate what your input data look like? At the moment `t` is samples from the truncated exponential and there's no values to predict given `t`. Is that all you have or do you have `x,y` pairs which could be simulated using `x=np.arange(0,10,0.1)` and then `y=np.exp(-x)/(1-np.exp(-lambda)`. In the latter case y would be your (simulated) observable.

Comment: @balleveryday, I am trying to predict the value of the decay constant(=1) or the scale factor of the truncated exponential distribution. The array t contains the artificial data. I apply Bayes's rule on this data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few things going on:

- when the sampler first starts it has a tuning phase; samples during this phase are discarded by default, but this can be controlled with the `discard_tuned_samples` argument
- the keys in the `start` argument dictionary need to correspond to the name given to the RandomVariable (`'$\lambda$'`) not the Python variable

Incorporating those two, one can try

```python
trace = pm.sample(20, start = {'$\lambda$': 10.},
            step=pm.Metropolis(), chains=1, cores=1,
            discard_tuned_samples=False)
```

However, the other possible issue is that

- the starting value isn't guaranteed to be emitted in the first draw; only if the first proposal sample is rejected, which is down to chance.

Fixing the game (setting a random seed), though, we can get glimpse:

```python
trace = pm.sample(20, start = {'$\lambda$': 10.},
            step=pm.Metropolis(), chains=1, cores=1,
            discard_tuned_samples=False, random_seed=1)

...

trace.get_values(varname='$\lambda$')[:10]

# array([10.        ,  5.42397358,  3.19841997,  1.09383329,  1.09383329,
#         1.09383329,  1.09383329,  1.09383329,  1.09383329,  1.09383329])
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is super helpful and has almost solved my problem. I just want to clarify what you mean by "starting value isn't guaranteed to be emitted in the first draw". Do you mean the starting value itself gets accepted or rejected depending on whether the  min(1,Hastings ratio) > u is true or false, where u is sampled from a uniform distribution(0,1)?

Comment: @singularity good question. Yes, that's what I think happens. The initial value specifies the location in state space from which the first proposal is generated. If that proposal gets rejected (along the lines you mention for Metropolis-Hastings), then the initial value will be emitted as the first draw. At a higher level, it should make sense for PyMC3 not to include the initial state as a "draw" by default because *by definition* it includes only prior information, whereas the point of MCMC is for draws to be emitted according to the posterior.

Comment: If you're trying to "restart" the metropolis process with the `trace` argument, and it doesn't work, consider not setting the `trace`, but instead setting `start = <your_old_trace>.point(-1)`. This worked for me on pymc3 3.11.4.